# Python Not Responding when I Run it

Tags: python, pygame

Python doesn't respond when I play it. No syntax error appears either. Not sure what is wrong. I tried running another game I made which worked fine so I don't think it's my computer.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJfbW.png)

This is my code:

```
import pygame 

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Draft")

icon = pygame.image.load("doctor.png")

pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0) red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

def draw_ground():
    groundx = 20
    groundy = 30
    Ground = pygame.Rect(groundx,groundy,width = 800,height = 20)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,Ground)

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    draw_ground()
```

It isn't complete yet, I'm trying to test it first before moving ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your code:

> ```py
> black = (0,0,0) red = (255,0,0)
> ```

It has to be

```py
black = (0,0,0) 
red = (255,0,0)
```

However, there is more.

---

`pygame.Rect` does not accept keyword arguments:

<s>`Ground = pygame.Rect(groundx,groundy,width = 800,height = 20)`</s>

```py
Ground = pygame.Rect(groundx,groundy,800,20)
```

---

You have to update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # clear dispaly
    screen.fill(0)

    # draw objects
    draw_ground()

    # update dispaly
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)